# Magento 2. Add attribute to Catalog Price Rule

Tags: magento2, attributes, catalog-price-rules, custom-attributes

Is it possible to add additional (simple string) attribute to the Catalog Price Rule? If it is, please, tell about it in details. Better with working code example.

**[UPD]**

I mean **add attribute to the price rule itself**.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is pretty easy to do this in Magento 2.1. You need to add a row to the `catalogrule` table using the module (in your own module):

`app/code/Vendor/Rules/Setup/InstallSchema.php`

```
namespace Vendor\Rules\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{

    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();

        $installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
            $installer->getTable('catalogrule'),
            'test_column',
            [
                'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                'length' => 32,
                'nullable' => false,
                'default' => '',
                'comment' => 'Test Column'
            ]
        );

        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Then, add a UI form update to the catalog rule form in your module:

`app/code/Vendor/Rules/view/adminhtml/ui_component/catalog_rule_form.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="rule_information">
        <field name="test_column">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Test Column</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">catalog_rule</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">test_column</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">50</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

The result will be the following:

[image]

Data save will be working on default:

[image]

You can add your own fieldset with fields in the same way.

Comment: Yes, I did it, but Image uploader not working. Text works, but image uploader...not.

Comment: @D.R. You wrote: Is it possible to add additional (***simple string***) attribute to the Catalog Price Rule
If you face the problem with the file input type, then, please, accept this answer and create a new topic to not mislead those who will come from Google. We'll try to help you.

Comment: oh, you are right. Thanks. Of course, I will. Just have no sleep for a long time)

Comment: here is the link http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/139897/magento-2-add-attribute-image-to-catalog-price-rule

Answer (score 1):

yes its Possible

***GO to Store => Attributes => product***

Then Select attribute that you want to show in Catalog Price Rule

Let say example i selected Color => Go to Storefront Properties &  then select 
**Use for Promo Rule Conditions**  => Yes & save

Run the below Command

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Check now on catalog Price Rule

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I mean add attribute to the price rule itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy entire `catalog_rule_form.xml` to your `ui_component`, clean cache and done.

Here is my file path
`magento2-root/src/app/code/Love/OneRoom/view/adminhtml/ui_component/catalog_rule_form.xml`