# Magento 2. Add attribute (image) to Catalog Price Rule

Tags: magento2, catalog-price-rules

Is it possible to add additional (image with Image Uploader) attribute to the Catalog Price Rule? If it is, please, tell about it in details. Better with working code example.

**What I have now**

Now I have only field with image uploader, but it just shows spinner and nothing more.

[image]

[image]

**Code example**

```
        <field name="img">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Image</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">catalog_rule</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
                    <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item>
                    <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/image-preview</item
                    <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="string">catalog_rule/promo_catalog/image</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
```

**[UPD]**

I have no `frontend/routes.xml` in my module. `module-catalog-rule` also doesn't have it. I use DI to inject ModelCollectionFactory of this module, where I need it.

Comment: Add your fronted routes.xml code to question.

Comment: @SHPatel I've updated the question.

Comment: catalog_rule/promo_catalog/image you have used it but this path must be correct. run it direct form URL and check it controller action is call or not. add your image.php file code. you can get more information from here : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/138928/add-new-image-attribute-for-category-in-magento-2-1-1/139648